# onKeyDown in fullscreen VrPanoramaView

Tags: android, google-cardboard

I have an activity with a `VrPanoramaView` and a `onKeyDown` method defined to work with a gamepad.
It all works great but, *when I change VrPanoramaView to fullscreen* (manually or on code), *the onKeyDown method stops being called*.

Is there any way of make it work?